# Passing Instance to Django formset

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

How to pass a instance to the Django formset,
The Scenario is like this. I have updated multiple rows by using a formset and, in a later stage i need to edit those values which i added earlier.(Editing)

```
q = PaymentLines.objects.filter(pay_lines=project)
formset = PayFormSet(prefix='payment', instance=q)
```

Answer (score 10):

```
AuthorFormSet(queryset=Author.objects.all())
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset

Comment: What if we want to pass an unsaved instance to the formset?

Answer (score 5):

I have used it as follows the formset used is [inlineformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.inlineformset_factory).

```
q = Projects.objects.get(pk=project)

formset = PayFormSet(prefix='payment',instance=q)
```

and then pass the formset to the template